# button not toggling for the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a button and for the first time it is not toggling when it is unchecked...

i have to press twice to make it toggle after that it is working well ....
and my code is as follows ...

```
-(IBAction)toggleAutomaticlogin:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag]==1)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:0];
    }           
    else if([sender tag]==0)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:1];          
    }
}
```

after clicking twice for the first time it is working well...

Comment: You might try just taking out your else if, also you might want to make sure that the image you have initially loaded is correct or it may take an extra press for it to change to what you expect.

Comment: I think @Ian is right. you should check the tag as well may be print it.

Comment: I just noticed, you never close your if statement either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with the tags you can also do something like

```
-(IBAction)toggleAutomaticlogin:(id)sender
{
    if([sender currentImage]== [UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox.png"])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code.

```
-(IBAction)toggleAutomaticlogin:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag]== 0)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:1];


    else if([sender tag]==1)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:0];

    }
}
```